# Getting 400 Bad Request Response from Facebook Graph API using jQuery.ajax

Tags: ajax, facebook-graph-api

I want to send a message whenever a button is clicked, but I'm getting 400 Bad Request Errors. It works fine when I do it in Postman.

Here's my jQuery.ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/me/messages?access_token=<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    data: {
        "recipient": {
            "id": psid
        },
        "message": {
            "text": "hello, world!"
        }
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
})
```

Comment: You say you are sending JSON, but you aren't. Quote jQuery docs: _"When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to false. For example, `{ a: "bc", d: "e,f" }` is converted to the string `a=bc&d=e%2Cf`."_

Comment: @CBroe you're a lifesaver! I should really learn how to read documentations next time.